# Install Open MPI mac and run mpicc and mpiexec on c programming file

Tags: c, openmpi

I want to install Open MPI on my MacBook Pro, and use terminal to run mpicc and mpiexec for my c programming file.

How can do it after I download the file(openmpi-3.0.0.tar.gz) from
https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v3.0/???

Comment: This basically asking for a tutorial, which is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: FWIW, Open MPI is packaged by brew, which makes installation trivial.